# solr runtime exception when indexing with Ukranian

Tags: solr

WHen I add a document with Ukranian to the Solr index, I get the following runtime error from Solr

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: morfologik/stemming/IStemmer   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.sendError(HttpSolrCall.java:593)
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:465)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: morfologik/stemming/IStemmer  at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.morfologik.MorfologikFilterFactory.create(MorfologikFilterFactory.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain.createComponents(TokenizerChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper.createComponents(AnalyzerWrapper.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper.createComponents(AnalyzerWrapper.java:101)
>     at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:179)
>     at org.apache.lucene.document.Field.tokenStream(Field.java:564)     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:606)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:344)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:458)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1363)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:163)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:955)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1110)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:706)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:250)
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2064)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:654)
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:450)
>     ... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   morfologik.stemming.IStemmer  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:793)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 50 more

I use code like this (in PHP) to add the document

```
<?php
    $solrInputDocument = new SolrInputDocument();
    $solrInputDocument->addField('id', 'iscar-hk uk 1 1', 1);
    $solrInputDocument->addField('product_id_i', '1', 1);
    $solrInputDocument->addField('type_i', 1, 1);
    $solrInputDocument->addField('lang_code_s', 'uk', 1);
    $solrInputDocument->addField('system_instance_s', 'iscar-hk', 1);
    $solrInputDocument->addField('hello_tuk', 'abc', 1);
    $docs = array($solrInputDocument);
    $solrClient->getSolrClient()->addDocuments($docs);
```

I use the following in my schema to to define Ukranian fields:

```
<dynamicField name="*_tuk"  type="text_uk"    indexed="true"  stored="true" />
<fieldType name="text_uk" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_uk.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In solrconfig.xml , I specifify the path of the mofologik analyzer.

```
  <lib dir="/opt/solr/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs" regex="lucene-analyzers-morfologik-5\.2\.1\.jar" />
```

I have checked that the path is correct.

Comment: The error is caused by the actual morfologik library not being found - i.e. it's not available on the classpath. The startup log for Solr will show you exactly which jars are being loaded, make sure the morfologik file is included (you can start by loading all the jars instead of just a single one). Unpack the jar and check if the interface referenced is present. Check if there's an additional morfologik library that needs adding.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Solr you need to manually request in your `solrconfig.xml` to include the path where the `MorfologikFilterFactory` is stored (typically  $SOLR_HOME/contrib/analysis-extras/lib/).

You might need to add the following two lines (or similar) to your `solrconfig.xml` and reload your core.

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

See also https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/language-analysis.html#ukrainian

Comment: It was specified in solrconfig.xml , and I edited the question to convey this at the end.